# Is the Magento 2 file system allowed to be owned by www-data? + Permissions question

Tags: magento2, security, server-setup, file-permissions, apache

I work at a company where I noticed that most of our Magento 2 file system is owned by `www-data` and in the `www-data` group on our Ubuntu server.
Furthermore, the docroot directory `/var/www/<websitename>` has the same ownership, and an exceeding amount of directories in the Magento file system have both `www-data` ownership and `777` permissions, e.g. `app`, `bin`, `pub` and `var` amongst others.
The main user that is used for CLI work is not in the `www-data` group.

Is this an acceptable practice in some situations? Or is it always bad practice? Should I tell the webmaster to consider changing this?
I consider this to be unnecessary and a dangerous security vulnerability, but I want to know whether it's permissible in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice in a production environment for the Magento file owner / command-line user and the web server user to use the same account (i.e. www-data) and may cause security issues and problems when running cron jobs.

> Some web servers run as www-data. Web content should not be owned by
> this user, or a compromised web server would be able to rewrite a web
> site. Data written out by web servers will be owned by www-data.

Follow the recommendations in the development documentation and configure separate users and permissions for the Magento 2 file owner and web server.

- The file owner / command-line user user should always be a member of
  the web server user group.
- Ensure that you run Magento 2 cron jobs as the file owner user.
- Always run Magento system commands such as *setup:upgrade* as the file
  owner / command-line user.

More info here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you mind adding some info about how using www-data ownership can compromise the server?

Comment: Thank you, I found your quote in /usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.html!